# Как извлечь часть вывода команды из cmd, для последующей обработки в другой команде?

Tags: windows, cmd, dos, txt

Есть 2 команды, которые выполняются последовательно с участием человека:

`bcdedit /copy {default} /d "Безопасный режим"`

В cmd выводится сгенерированный id:

`Запись успешно скопирована в {ac9972ad-9559-11ea-81fe-14dae9ab9c25}.`

Так вот, нужно извлечь само выражение `{ac9972ad-9559-11ea-81fe-14dae9ab9c25}` из этого вывода и добавить ее в переменную для дальнейшего использования в следующей команде:

`bcdedit /set %отобразившийся_GUID% safeboot minimal`

Лучше, если возможно, без парсинга дополнительно созданного файла те

`bcdedit /copy {default} /d "Безопасный режим" > file.txt`

Возможно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все равно парсить придется. Чисто технический вопрос, а какой файл придется парсить: обычный текстовый или STDOUT.

```
@for /f "delims={ tokens=2*" %%i in ('@bcdedit /copy {default} /d "Безопасный режим"') do @set guid=%%i
@set guid={%guid:~0,37%
@echo bcdedit /set %guid% safeboot minimal
```

Следует не забывать, что в приведенном примере батника (работающем от админа) нужно соблюдать требуемую кодировку при использовании кириллицы.

Comment: Не обязательно нельзя использовать парсинг, лиж бы работал без создания файла. Создание правильной кодировки не проблема

Comment: Все работает идеально, спасибо

Comment: И еще, что будет, если в выводе будет 2 символа ```(``` те будет выведен 2 ```guid```?

Comment: Парсится по фигурной скобке **{** с помощью оператора **FOR**. Все что после открывающей фигурной скобки считается одним значением и урезается до 37 символов (включая закрывающую фигурную скобку) = длина строкового значения GUID + 1

Comment: Это понятно, но если например из ```Запись успешно скопирована в {ac9972ad-9559-11ea-81fe-14dae9ab9c25} в путь по адресу {14dae9ab9c25}``` и потребуется все что во второй скобке, то как быть

Comment: всего лишь добавить чуть кода в первую строку. В первой строке обрабатывать переменную **%%j** - помещая её значение в строковую переменную. Которую можно будет потом использовать по своему усмотрению.